# PlayStation 2 Slim with analog A/V output having noise interference issues

Tags: gaming, audio, sony-playstation, troubleshooting

I'm having an odd issue with the aforementioned system, the A/V receiver is a RCA STAV-4180 unit, and being from 1996, it's still a great unit. So far, while it's tape output for recording does have noise coupling issues, none of the inputs do. The buzzing only happens with the PS2 and goes away when the PS2 is turned off. I've done a lot of troubleshooting and can't find anywhere else that the buzzing is coming from. Any tips? I think the cable itself may be the point of ingress for the interference, but am unsure.

Comment: Is the "buzzing" on the sound output, or to be heard from inside the RCA unit itself? Have you tried using a replacement cable? An inexpensive cable would be enough for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting decent PS2 cable with RF shielding. I had the same issue when connected to TV, even though console's audio was muted.